# partitioning in existing mysql table

Tags: mysql, partitioning

We have a table cn_audit_log. which we thinking about partitioning. we like to partition by 6 months of data with LOGDATE.
what will be the query to achieve it.

```
mysql> select count(*) from cn_audit_log;

| count(*)  |
+-----------+
| 392176871 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (26 min 39.98 sec)

cn_audit_log_overflow

+---------------------+
| max(LOGDATE)        |
+---------------------+
| 2017-09-11 11:38:52 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select min(LOGDATE) from cn_audit_log;

+---------------------+
| min(LOGDATE)        |
+---------------------+
| 2014-10-07 10:45:36 |


mysql> show create table cn_audit_log \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: cn_audit_log
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `cn_audit_log` (
  `AUDITLOGID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `APPID` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACTIONCODE` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOGDATE` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `MESSAGE` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `PROFILEID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `APPVERSION` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACTIONSUBCODE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADMINUSER` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AUDITLOGID`),
  KEY `CN_AUDIT_LOG_DT_DESC` (`LOGDATE`),
  KEY `CN_AUDIT_LOG_EMAIL_IDX` (`EMAIL`,`LOGDATE`),
  KEY `CN_AUDIT_LOG_PROFILEID` (`PROFILEID`,`LOGDATE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=879116169 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Are you partitioning only NEW data, or all existing data?  Can you get any downtime?  

@RickJames has a great article about Range Partitioning on his site that you should read.. http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: MySQL 5.6.34 ..partitioning all existing data.. yes for downtime and is it possible to do without downtime?

Comment: Please include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE cn_audit_log` in your question. Just using `DESC cn_audit_log` doesn't give enough information about indexes. Also give an example of a query against this table that you want to optimize by using partitioning.

Comment: A lot of those columns smell like they could (and should) be turned into ids and lookup tables.  This would shrink the log significantly; perhaps to 1/4 of its current size.

Answer (score 0):

The table has about 36 months of data; what do you mean by "partition by 6 months"?  Perhaps 7 partitions of 6 months each?

What do you hope to gain?  Is there some query that you think will run faster?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (not the wimply `DESCRIBE TABLES`) and the `SELECT`.

I will then try to convince you of a `INDEX` that will let a variant of that `SELECT` run as fast or faster then via partitioning.

Only if I fail at that will I help you create the partitions.  Is it a deal?

It may be possible to create the partitioned (or properly indexed) table with only a small downtime.

**Partitioning notes**

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

`PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(LOGDATE))`

Will you be keeping 36 months' data?  If so, I recommend 38 monthly partitions or 14 quarterly.  Then `DROP` and `REORGANIZE` monthly or quarterly.

The PK would need `LOGDATE` added on the end.

If you intend to "archive" the `DROPped` partition, use "transportable tablespaces" to detach the partition and turn it into a table.  Then dump (or whatever) that table.

As for low-downtime:  Look at `pt-query-digest` and `gh-ost`.  I do not  have direct experience with either (in this context), so I have to stop, saying "either tool should make allow for rebuilding the table as partitioned with very little downtime".

Comment: we planning to maintain the database table seperately so we can delete the old data's.

Comment: Then you want a sliding set of partitions in a single table.  I discuss that in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: More details added.